# How to access static variables in PHP in the same line

Tags: php, static

First of all, I can't think a better title, because I don't know what is the name of this method.

Consider the following (this is what I have now and is working):

```
$settingsValueColumn = self::$settingsValueColumn;
return $model->$settingsValueColumn;
```

Which evaluates as $model->someName

If the property wouldn't be static, I could just do:

```
return $model->$this->settingsValueColumn;
```

But doing this:

```
return $model->self::$settingsValueColumn;
```

Is syntax error.

Maybe it is meant to be written different. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```php
return $model->{self::$settingsValueColumn};
```

Comment: And I would be VERY afraid of using such dynamic code - it is a sign of bad design most of the time!

Comment: No argument from me. I suppose I could have put a disclaimer, but I'll let your comment do that for me.

Comment: @Sven it is my first plugin for Yii, I surely can learn from your experience, if you want to help me redisigning / building it, go to http://tracker.fusiondev.com.ar, thanks!

Comment: I have no time for yet another project. But two things for you to think about: 1. Why make the property dynamic? If you don't know the name beforehand, make it an access to an array, or have a getter that accepts the name and returns a value. And 2. why make the property name a static variable? If one instance changes that name, all other objects are also affected - and this is an unwanted side effect and will create hard to trace bugs.